# Trouble Constraint Animation in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

I want the likeButton to fly in from outside the view to a constraint of 2 when I use the tapGesture. The likeButton appears where I need it to be when I tap, but there is no animation to get it there. Still have a lot to learn when it comes to animations. Anything helps, Thank you!! The constraint is currently set to just outside the view at -80.

```
@objc func handleTapGesture(gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = gestureReconizer.location(in: messageTableView)

    let indexPath = messageTableView.indexPathForRow(at: p)

    let cellAnimate = messageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath!) as! CustomMessageCell
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {

                cellAnimate.likeButtonContraint.constant = 2
                cellAnimate.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
let cellAnimate = messageTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customMessageCell", for: indexPath!) as! CustomMessageCell
```

do

```
let cellAnimate = messageTableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath!) as! CustomMessageCell
```

As `dequeueReusableCell` returns another cell for reusing not the one you expect that's at the indexPath you supplied

//

```
let cellAnimate = messageTableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath!) as! CustomMessageCell
cellAnimate.likeButtonContraint.constant = 2
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   cellAnimate.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```